# How to do math operation in apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm programming and Addon for Google Sheet, but when I try to do math operations (add) the two values are concatenated not added.

For example, if I try **1+2** I get **12**, instead of **3**.

How can I perform in Apps Script?

Comment: Sounds like you're adding strings. Try `parseInt()` to convert those strings to integers before adding them. E.g. `var a = parseInt("1", 10)`, `var b = parseInt("2", 10)`, then `a + b` should give 3.

Comment: Interesting, that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I probably should have submitted that as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your code. Hope this helps. Parsing characters as int.

```
function myFunction() {
  Logger.log("Here");
  var a = parseInt('2');
  var b = parseInt('3');
  Logger.log(a + b);      --// this should log 5
}
```

Comment: Because it is javascript. You just took my comment and posted it as an answer, replacing '1' and '2' with '2' and '3'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just convert the value to a number using Number(), then you can add it. This works better for me, because you don't have to convert to an integer and lose the decimals if your working with numbers.

Number("1") + Number("2") = 3

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem myself. However, I don't think it was an issue with strings, as multiplication, division, and subtraction all worked as expected.
As a workaround, I used 1-(-2)
This worked like a charm, and my head hurts.